# present perfect Vs present prefect continuous

Tags: present-perfect

Complete the following exercise:

> I am learning English. I ____________ English for six months (Learn).

I know that **present perfect** and **present prefect continuous** are used to talk about actions that started in the past and still continuing until now. In my grammar book, though, it says that the answer is **have been learning**. Why?

I have read :

https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html
https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfectcontinuous.html

Comment: Related ELL question [_What is the perfect?_](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it)

Answer (score 1):

"I have learnt" means "I have completed the learning and now I know something".  This is part of the meaning of "learn".

So in this case, when you want to indicate an ongoing process of learning, the present continuous tense is appropriate.

Note that this is part of the meaning of "learn" in many cases the present perfect and present perfect continuous have very similar meanings.